# How to upload pdf and tex file to the mysql database without saving it into the local system using pylatex and python

Tags: python, pylatex, mysql

I want the pdf file and the tex files to be saved directly into the database without saving them into the local system using pylatex and python. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Briefly, idea is to use pipeline. One program creates pdf, another saves binary stream into database.

Comment: tex needs write access to the filesystem for log file and aux file etc as well as the final pdf, so it is likely to be simplest to submit the pdf after the tex run using python or whatever database connector you are using.